# Groovy script to set header with timestamp

Tags: groovy

I am working on an integration scenario using SAP HANA cloud integrations solutions. The requirement is that I need to make an API call every 15 mins so to make this call I need to set the header in which the time needs to increment every 15 mins. Example of how I want to set the header is below.

```
    From                        To  
    Date    Time                Date    Time
11:00:05    1-Jun   10:45:01    1-Jun   11:00:00
11:15:02    1-Jun   11:00:01    1-Jun   11:15:00
11:30:03    1-Jun   11:15:01    1-Jun   11:30:00
11:45:02    1-Jun   11:30:01    1-Jun   11:45:00
12:00:04    1-Jun   11:45:01    1-Jun   12:00:00
```

My flow looks as below. I need to add the script after content modifier. I am trying multiple things and it is not working.

[the flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaiyw.png)

```
import com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message; 
import java.util.HashMap; 
import java.lang.*; 

def Message processData(Message message){ 
    def url = "app.ticketmaster.com/sth-customer/…"; 
    message.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json"); 
    message.setHeader("Accept","application/json"); 
    message.setProperty("url",url); 
    return message; 
}
```

Comment: could you share your code to call api? what exactly is not working?

Comment: No, I don't have a code. The reason being am using integration services of SAP cloud platform and using which I can configure the parameters. But in this case, I need to get a script. I am not sure how to send a method which caculates the date from and to and increments current date by 15 mins. I have a script which can make API calls but dont know how to set the date calculation in the header.

Comment: Please find my script below.

Comment: Please find the script below

Comment: import com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.lang.*;
def Message processData(Message message){
def url = "https://app.ticketmaster.com/sth-customer/ticketing_services.aspx?dsn=apigee&apikey=c4QMMWnX7WbQrXVtlRgldWJBF0fKVqr3";
message.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
message.setHeader("Accept","application/json");
message.setProperty("url",url);
return message;
}